# Multiplexing buttons using shift register - high impedance output

Tags: integrated-circuit, multiplexer, high-impedance

I have experience with 74HC4094, and I believe the 74HC595 is essentially the same - the datasheet says they have "tristate output", but that is only when OE is low - then all pins are tristate.

What I'd want is that high would be high, and low would put the output pin in high impedance mode (aka tristate). It is intended for multiplexing buttons, in order to save IO pins on the micro.

How to achieve this, best?

- Is there some other chip with this functionality - or maybe, how can I do it myself?
- I thought of adding diodes to the output, but it'll probably not work good, because of the voltage drop.
- Maybe there's some other solution, like chip specifically meant for multiplexing buttons?

With the diodes, it'd be something like:

```
--u--+           +-------------//--+
     |---data-->-|                 |->- to next shift reg.
  uc |--clock-->-|  shift register |->-
     |--store-->-|                 |->-
     |           +-------------//--+
     |             |    |    |
     |             V    V    V diodes
     |             |    |    |
     |              |-   |-   |-   buttons
     |             |    |    |
     |-<--sense----o----o----o---
-----+
```

I'd just send 1 to data, and then zeros, moving the 1 through all my buttons. The "sense" wire would have pull-down (or pull-up if the diodes were reversed).

Comment: Would low/hi-Z work instead?

Comment: yeah, actually that's even better, as I can use internal pullup for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need 8 switches or fewer, you could use the same three port pins and a 74HC4051. Each switch goes to ground and to an input, and the output of the multiplexer goes to the micro using an internal pullup (in practice you may wish to add some stuff to deal with ESD from the switches, but that's outside the scope of this answer).

So you would simply put a 3-bit address on the three port pins and read off the state on the input- one part total.

Edit: if you really want to use shift registers you could use parallel-in serial out registers with a pull-up per switch or use one of the '595 variants that has **open drain** outputs (TI TPIC series such as [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf) one). Most designers will put the switches in an XY matrix when there gets to be that many,to reduce parts count and minimize cost in a production situation, but you're free to make your own trade-offs.

Comment: That's a nice chip, but I thought more like 20 or more buttons  - with the shift regs, I can get almost any number of pins I'd want.

Comment: See edit above. I thought from his comment that @Ignacio was going to suggest this or I would have added it in the original answer.

Comment: Looks good, I'll give the 4021 a try. Using matrix is good, but you need too many pins for that - pins are precious :)

Answer (score 2):

A hi-Z/low output is a characteristic of [**open collector/open drain**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) outputs. Of the logic devices that have such, the simplest is the 74'07 hex buffer. More complex instances include the 74HCT7273 octal D flip-flop and the SN74BCT760 octal driver.

Comment: Yep, open collector sounds like the thing, but those things you suggested aren't shift registers or very usable for me - the 74*07 would do the trick, but then I'd need two chips per each 8 buttons, which isn't too nice - pricey and also more soldering.

Comment: OD is not terribly popular, so you won't find too many discrete chips with it. You could use something like the SN74LVC3G07 to reduce wastage, but there will still be plenty of soldering.